# How to remove defacto duplicates returned by here autocomplete API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am fetching data from the here autocomplete rest endpoint. It works fine, but for example searching for `berlin` returns me 3 results, which are (at least in my usecase) defacto the same ... I assume `berlin` is found as state, city and area or something, but since this will be the same area I consider it to be duplicates ...

[image: example results for berlin]

I tried playing around with the `resultType`-attribute, but using `area` gives the same behavior. If I use `city` I have to enter all letters of `berlin` to get the suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

you can try  `resultType=city&country=DEU&query=Ber` with country filter you need not to enter all the letters of berlin to get the suggestion and all with no duplicate.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/resource-suggest.html

Hope this helps !

Comment: Not really, because I do want the search to be worldwide.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have to the new version coming out in a few weeks and it seems this issue is fixed:

Current:
[Current behavior for HERE autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeVGR.png)

View of upcoming version:

[Preview of latest behavior for HERE autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4d1Y.png)

Comment: Can you add anymore information about this new version?